# How to add a MySql database and user to another table and user?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let me explain it to you what actually I'm looking for.

For example: we crated two databases and users in MySql

> **1. Database Name:  Test1   /    MySQL User: Test1**
>    **2. Database Name:  Test2  /  MySQL User: Test2**

in Datebase and user **Test1**, we installed a website template including user registration and login and etc

and in database and user **Test2**, we installed ticketing system

- If an user will register an account in website, his username and
  password will store in table **pt_account** in **Test1** database test
- If an user will register an account in ticketing system, his username
  and password will store in table **ticket_account** in **Test2** database test

Here is my question:

> How to connect these two tables **pt_account**  and **ticket_account**
>   to each other, I mean user will be able to login into ticketing system and
>   submit ticket with his/her username and password that he registered in website, no need to register
>   account for ticketing system.

Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: when the user inputs the user details you can check for it in both the tables and if match is found , you may let him continue

Comment: Why not in a same db. You need to have same username to connect two db.

Comment: The best option in authenticating among distributed systems would be to use oauth, but if it is as simple as 2 systems as yours, you can have the registration method in both systems to create the user in both tables or have a synchronization service running in the backed that does the same job or you can have the tables in sync or use @Rishi suggestion to have a single table

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do! but its better to create an api on website and use that for login in another project instead of duplicate username and password.

you can create a Webservice for Check Username and password and Simply call it with other websites and applications.
in this case, last status of users already exists and for future items, simply add a method to this webservice, for example, change password or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) to achieve this if databases are hosted on same MySQL instance. If table structure is same, it is very simple:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Test2.ticket_account AS SELECT * FROM Test1.pt_account
```